# como obtengo el id de un elemento al pasarle el cursor

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom

estoy intentando hacer como un sistema de calificación de un producto con estrellas, que cuando se le pase el mouse por alguna de las estrellas, una variable obtenga el id, y que ese id (que son numeros) sirva como indice para mostrar el elemento del vector de calificaiones, abajo de las estrellas, e intentado acceder a los elementos hijos ya que antes de que se pase el cursor por alguna estrella, primero toca la clase "puntuaciones". Entonces no se como podria hacer eso
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
javascript
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]resultado esperado

Comment: Agrega tu código HTML junto con lo que hayas intentado por favor

Comment: Puedes asignarle un evento a cada uno y cuando le dé a uno de ellos, recorrer un for desde 1 hasta el id donde esta posicionado  e ir coloreandolos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo no añadiría el evento a la clase principal mas bien lo agregaría sobre cada ítem, de tu calificación.

Cuando el cursor pase sobre cada elemento, puedo acceder a ese ítem, a sus propiedades y a los items, de el mismo padre para generar el efecto de asignar la calificación.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calificaciones = ["mala", "regular", "buena", "muy buena", "excelente"];
    var aux1 = document.querySelectorAll(".puntuaciones>a");
    var calif = document.querySelector(".puntuaciones .calificacion");
    for (const item of aux1) {
        item.addEventListener('mouseenter', cal);
    }
    function cal(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var auxi = parseInt(e.target.id);
        var elementos = e.target.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".puntuaciones>a");

        //Quito la clase a todos, no hago un toggle por que cuando sea el cambio a un elemento superior me quitara los anteriores
        Array.from(elementos).forEach(e => e.classList.remove("seleccionado"));

        //fitlo por los que el atributo id sea menor a el actual y en el foreach le asigno la clase seleccionado
        Array.from(elementos).filter(item => { return parseInt(item.id) <= auxi })
            .forEach(e => e.classList.add("seleccionado"));

        //obtengo la calificación y la asigno.
        calif.innerHTML = `${calificaciones[auxi - 1]}`;
    }
});
```

```css
.puntuaciones a i {
    color: lightblue;
}
.puntuaciones a.seleccionado i {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" />


    <div class="puntuaciones">
        <a href="#" id="1"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="2"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="3"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="4"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="5"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></a>
        <br />
        <span class="calificacion"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero ¿por qué usar _jQuery_? Puedes evitarlo con `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ... aquí el código ...});`

Comment: Solo ocupaba algo rápido para tener acceso al dom hasta que este cargado, lo que me interesaba era la función en si

Comment: Precisamente, la línea que puse en el comentario hace lo mismo.

Comment: ya la edite para quitar la dependencia al Jquery, Gracias

Comment: ¡Excelente! Mucho mejor ahora. +1

Comment: exactamente eso era, muchas gracias, es que apenas y empiezo en javascript y me surgio esa idea de un momento a otro.